# Which foreign key to use in a many-to-one table

Tags: sql, mysql, database, foreign-keys

Suppose I have a table Books with columns Book_ID (Primary Key), ISBN (Unique), and several others such as Title/author/etc.

I have another table Sales, with primary key Sale_ID, a foreign key to link to Books, and other fields with info on Sales.  Sales only exist for books with ISBNs.  Is it better database design to have Book_ID or ISBN be the primary key.  Note: I will be LEFT JOINing Sales to Books on whichever the foreign key is chosen.

UPDATE: Some Books have no ISBN's because they're not published with them.  However, I don't foresee (at least in the next several years) users being able to sell them, because I have no system for making sure that a given book w/o the ISBN isn't repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I think I would go for the [surrogate primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) `book_id` as the foreign key.

There are a few potential issues that I can identify if you were to use the non-primary key `ISBN` as a foreign key:

- You might have a missing or unknown `ISBN` for a particular book. What would you do in case there is a sale of that book?
- You might have an incorrect `ISBN`. To edit it, you would have to update all the tables that would be using it as a foreign key.
- You might want to start selling books that don't have an `ISBN` in the future. Why are you storing books without an `ISBN` in the first place?
- An index on `book_id` should be much more compact than one on an `ISBN` field.

Comment: Updated my question to with info on NULL ISBN Books.

Answer (score 0):

I would always use your primary key

Answer (score 0):

I would always use `ISBN`. This way you have a simple way of enforcing your business rule, "Sales only exist for books with ISBNs" i.e. by making the `ISBN` column `NOT NULL` in the `Sales` table and referencing the `ISBN` column in the `Books` table.

I don't agree with @Daniel Vassallo that because you might want to start selling books that don't have an ISBN **in the future** you would want to drop the rule in the database today. There is a name for this design flaw: future creep. Also, the considerations of 'compact indexes' should always be secondary to those of basic data integrity.

Comment: I think you're giving too much importance to this business rule. Why is the OP storing books without an ISBN in the first place? ... Mine wasn't a concrete, "always do this, never do that" answer. I only iterated a few potential issues that I could identify, if the OP were to use the `ISBN` as a foreign key (in fact, I updated my answer with a couple more points).